# How to find deadlock location by dlv Goroutine information?

Tags: go

My program occasionally appears to be unresponsive.

I tried to add such a log code to the main function of the program, but this log is also not output when there is a failure.

```
go func() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
        fmt.Println("Hello World!")
    }
}()
```

So I checked the program running through the dlv tool. I found that the program has more than 50,000 Goroutines, when normally there should be only 500 or so.

In the Goroutine list, there are very many that look like deadlocks like this.

`Goroutine 19024799 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684384197s]`

I checked the execution stack information of this Goroutine and the result is as follows.

```
 0  0x000000000043a556 in runtime.gopark
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362
 1  0x000000000044b0b3 in runtime.goparkunlock
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:367
 2  0x000000000044b0b3 in runtime.semacquire1
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:144
 3  0x00000000004665a5 in sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71
 4  0x0000000000473785 in sync.(*Mutex).lockSlow
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/sync/mutex.go:162
 5  0x00000000004740bf in sync.(*Mutex).Lock
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/sync/mutex.go:81
 6  0x00000000004740bf in sync.(*Pool).pinSlow
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/sync/pool.go:213
 7  0x000000000047400e in sync.(*Pool).pin
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/sync/pool.go:206
 8  0x0000000000473d45 in sync.(*Pool).Get
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/sync/pool.go:128
 9  0x0000000000711e29 in net/http.newTextprotoReader
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/http/request.go:994
10  0x0000000000711fd9 in net/http.readRequest
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/http/request.go:1024
11  0x00000000007181ea in net/http.(*conn).readRequest
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/http/server.go:988
12  0x000000000071c58b in net/http.(*conn).serve
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/http/server.go:1891
13  0x0000000000721cce in net/http.(*Server).Serve.func3
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/http/server.go:3071
14  0x000000000046a641 in runtime.goexit
    at /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

But it doesn't have my code in it, which seems to be a problem with the net.http package?

Here is the complete Goroutine list information, how do I locate where the exact problem is? Also can you tell me why the logging code I added is not outputting either?

```
(dlv) grs
  Goroutine 1 - User: /home/xxxxxx/golibs/rpcserver/v2@v2.0.0/rpcserver/server.go:392 xxxx/golibs/rpcserver/v2/rpcserver.(*Server).waitHttp (0xd0c588) [select 452427h39m57.846100461s]
  Goroutine 2 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [force gc (idle) 452385h49m20.252083363s]
  Goroutine 3 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [finalizer wait 452427h39m57.869422736s]
  Goroutine 4 - User: /home/xxxxxx/devops/statsd@v0.0.13/client_golang/statsdlib/push.go:39 xxxxxx/devops/statsd/client_golang/statsdlib.statsdPushLoop (0x87b17e) [chan receive]
  Goroutine 9 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 10 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 15 - User: /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/gobiz/logger@v1.3.4/file.go:309 xxxxxx/gobiz/logger.(*fileLog).writeLoop (0x80a545) [select 452427h39m57.846215549s]
  Goroutine 16 - User: /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/disf/disf-go-spl-v2@v0.1.35/disf/common/watcher.go:49 xxxxxx/disf/disf-go-spl-v2/disf/common.(*DirWatcher).run.func1 (0x84a9f9) [chan receive]
  Goroutine 18 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC sweep wait]
  Goroutine 19 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC scavenge wait]
  Goroutine 27 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 28 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 29 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 30 - User: /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/platform-ha/onekey-degrade_sdk_go/v3@v3.2.11/degrade/metric.go:96 xxxxxx/platform-ha/onekey-degrade_sdk_go/v3/degrade.(*metricSender).sendMetricFromChan (0xb05e65) [chan receive 452427h39m57.86959434s]
  Goroutine 31 - User: /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/platform-ha/onekey-degrade_sdk_go/v3@v3.2.11/degrade/metric.go:96 xxxxxx/platform-ha/onekey-degrade_sdk_go/v3/degrade.(*metricSender).sendMetricFromChan (0xb05e65) [chan receive 452427h39m57.869609575s]
  Goroutine 34 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.683989625s]
  Goroutine 35 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684006698s]
  Goroutine 36 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684023352s]
  Goroutine 37 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684037091s]
  Goroutine 38 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684051841s]
  Goroutine 39 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684066197s]
  Goroutine 40 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684082165s]
  Goroutine 41 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684095326s]
  Goroutine 42 - User: /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/golibs/metrics@v0.2.3/metrics.go:280 xxxxxx/xxxx/golibs/metrics.(*Sender).asyncSendLoop.func1 (0x880a5b) [select 452391h19m51.199497773s]
  Goroutine 43 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68413238s]
  Goroutine 45 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/time.go:194 time.Sleep (0x46742e) [sleep]
  Goroutine 46 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.8518662s]
  Goroutine 48 - User: /gaia/workspace-job/xxxxxx/tech-es/hera-hotel/common/handlers/dd-apollo/apollo.go:50 hera-hotel/common/handlers/dd-apollo.OnConfigUpdate.func1 (0x884859) [chan receive 452427h39m57.863062571s]
  Goroutine 49 - User: /gaia/workspace-job/xxxxxx/tech-es/hera-hotel/common/handlers/dd-apollo/apollo.go:50 hera-hotel/common/handlers/dd-apollo.OnConfigUpdate.func1 (0x884859) [chan receive 452427h39m57.846560172s]
  Goroutine 67 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 68 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 69 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 72 - User: /home/xxxxxx/github.com/getsentry/sentry-go@v0.10.0/transport.go:378 github.com/getsentry/sentry-go.(*HTTPTransport).worker (0x8010ec) [chan receive 452391h19m51.973327187s]
  Goroutine 73 - User: /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/disf/disf-go-spl-v2@v0.1.35/disf/common/watcher.go:49 xxxxxx/disf/disf-go-spl-v2/disf/common.(*DirWatcher).run.func1 (0x84a9f9) [chan receive]
  Goroutine 75 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/database/sql/sql.go:1226 database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener (0xa3d38d) [select 452427h39m57.863183594s]
  Goroutine 84 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:151 os/signal.signal_recv (0x466bef) (thread 1238)
  Goroutine 98 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/fd_unix.go:172 net.(*netFD).accept (0x522b15) [IO wait]
  Goroutine 99 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/fd_unix.go:172 net.(*netFD).accept (0x522b15) [IO wait 452427h39m57.846699823s]
  Goroutine 100 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684348233s]
  Goroutine 101 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/fd_unix.go:172 net.(*netFD).accept (0x522b15) [IO wait]
  Goroutine 102 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43a556) [select 452427h39m57.846735781s]
* Goroutine 19024799 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684384197s]
  Goroutine 19168258 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684396903s]
  Goroutine 19913951 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684409102s]
  Goroutine 19958391 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684421539s]
  Goroutine 20081541 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684433615s]
  Goroutine 20116495 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684446142s]
  Goroutine 20172239 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68446185s]
  Goroutine 20207666 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684474196s]
  Goroutine 20220591 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684486066s]
  Goroutine 20268396 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68449908s]
  Goroutine 20276185 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684512538s]
  Goroutine 20313977 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684526483s]
  Goroutine 20316289 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684540806s]
  Goroutine 20318288 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684551403s]
  Goroutine 20318347 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684567108s]
  Goroutine 20319443 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684581059s]
  Goroutine 20323201 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684594231s]
  Goroutine 20325033 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684618502s]
  Goroutine 20328465 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684632661s]
  Goroutine 20335307 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684644756s]
  Goroutine 20397528 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m51.059188607s]
  Goroutine 20400764 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684673109s]
  Goroutine 20468196 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684687005s]
  Goroutine 20534187 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684699159s]
  Goroutine 20568898 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684715557s]
  Goroutine 20575172 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684729685s]
  Goroutine 20597278 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684743914s]
  Goroutine 20597598 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684756263s]
  Goroutine 20632136 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684770139s]
  Goroutine 20640497 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m51.200166135s]
  Goroutine 20650794 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684794291s]
  Goroutine 20660361 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684805975s]
  Goroutine 20663053 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684818251s]
  Goroutine 20663773 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684830839s]
  Goroutine 20664397 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684842823s]
  Goroutine 20665585 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684857771s]
  Goroutine 20666648 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684875668s]
  Goroutine 20687321 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684890405s]
  Goroutine 20707614 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68490266s]
  Goroutine 20718922 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684914223s]
  Goroutine 20757785 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684926164s]
  Goroutine 20829603 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684938115s]
  Goroutine 20835539 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684950162s]
  Goroutine 20835973 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68496274s]
  Goroutine 20839843 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684974214s]
  Goroutine 20840568 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684986303s]
  Goroutine 20848440 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.684998289s]
  Goroutine 20854500 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.6850127s]
  Goroutine 20854525 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685025015s]
  Goroutine 20863390 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685038516s]
  Goroutine 20866287 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685049886s]
  Goroutine 20877318 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685061775s]
  Goroutine 20891470 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68507689s]
  Goroutine 20956591 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685089221s]
  Goroutine 20957698 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68510479s]
  Goroutine 20961171 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685116705s]
  Goroutine 20973020 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685128477s]
  Goroutine 20973025 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685140136s]
  Goroutine 20975184 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685152465s]
  Goroutine 21001524 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685170802s]
  Goroutine 21012487 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685184665s]
  Goroutine 21013236 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685199431s]
  Goroutine 21013322 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685215529s]
  Goroutine 21032174 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685229559s]
  Goroutine 21032516 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68524425s]
  Goroutine 21032572 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685258494s]
  Goroutine 21039514 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685278904s]
  Goroutine 21045140 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685294451s]
  Goroutine 21084483 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685310301s]
  Goroutine 21093028 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685323634s]
  Goroutine 21107872 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685336561s]
  Goroutine 21108115 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m51.200734721s]
  Goroutine 21111514 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685370409s]
  Goroutine 21131488 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685383581s]
  Goroutine 21136991 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685395245s]
  Goroutine 21152770 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68541013s]
  Goroutine 21175241 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685422871s]
  Goroutine 21204561 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685434558s]
  Goroutine 21208091 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685448201s]
  Goroutine 21252257 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685460063s]
  Goroutine 21253699 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685473618s]
  Goroutine 21257543 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68548853s]
  Goroutine 21284391 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685499165s]
  Goroutine 21298916 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685512404s]
  Goroutine 21319323 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685524817s]
  Goroutine 21340070 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685537472s]
  Goroutine 21342501 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685549549s]
  Goroutine 21375867 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685559764s]
  Goroutine 21376711 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685574439s]
  Goroutine 21378245 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685586256s]
  Goroutine 21422035 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685599848s]
  Goroutine 21432940 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685622964s]
  Goroutine 21433080 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685638971s]
  Goroutine 21437865 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685652599s]
  Goroutine 21438006 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/fd_posix.go:55 net.(*netFD).Read (0x520a09) [IO wait 452391h19m52.276933224s]
  Goroutine 21438007 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/http/transport.go:2392 net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop (0x739855) [select 452391h19m52.581598589s]
  Goroutine 21447571 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685689681s]
  Goroutine 21448729 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.68570341s]
  Goroutine 21451141 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685716405s]
  Goroutine 21465051 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685735719s]
  Goroutine 21470163 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685745922s]
  Goroutine 21483387 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685758361s]
  Goroutine 21485244 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685770491s]
  Goroutine 21492675 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685782117s]
  Goroutine 21492989 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685794606s]
  Goroutine 21493868 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/fd_posix.go:55 net.(*netFD).Read (0x520a09) [IO wait 452391h19m51.201189916s]
  Goroutine 21493869 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/net/http/transport.go:2392 net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop (0x739855) [select 452391h19m51.363712951s]
  Goroutine 21499233 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685834687s]
  Goroutine 21499342 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685846508s]
  Goroutine 21505601 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h19m50.685858947s]
  Goroutine 21507198 - User: /usr/local/go1.18.3/src/runtime/sema.go:71 sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex (0x4665a5) [semacquire 452391h17m50.485131829s]
  ......(The latter is all duplicate content)
```